# Cargo Rack Suggestions?

Tags: rack

I recently bought a bicycle, and have found the need to purchase a cargo rack to go on the back of it.

After scouring Amazon looking for a reasonable one, I’ve discovered that, while there are many “brand names” they all use exact same image/version of cargo rack.

Anyone have any suggestions?

If it helps, I have a disc-brake system on my bicycle.

Thanks!

Comment: *while there are many “brand names” they all use exact same image/version of cargo rack.* Because they're all pretty much the same thing:  chunks of aluminum bent into a bicycle cargo rack. Probably all in the same factories in China. Find one that fits your bike, your budget, and your aesthetic tastes and don't worry too much about the "brand name".

Comment: Do you intend to carry a child's seat on/with this carrier?  If so, look at the mid-mount seat style instead, like the Weeride and similar.  They're a lot more fun for the kid, and better fore/aft weight distribution.

Comment: If you want to see a bunch of different rack styles, look at a bike shop like wiggle or CRC.com.   Amazon tends to inspire sameness.

Comment: There are many cargo racks that fit for disc break systems. More important is probably whether your frame is prepared for a cargo rack or not. So to get any useful advice, it would probably be best to provide at least the following information: what kind of bike do you have and is the frame prepared for a bike rack? What do you intend to do with the rack? What is your budget?

Answer (score 2):

This question I remember was about fitting rear racks to disc brake bikes, using quick release (QR) skewers. Seemingly, good ones are supplied with an extra long QR skewer to mount the rack: [Which holes to use for mounting rear rack?](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/56157/which-holes-to-use-for-mounting-rear-rack?r=SearchResults)

Comment: Yep, about half the difference between models is in how they mount.  If you have a bike that has rack eyelets on the rear dropouts you should prefer a rack that attaches to them.  A rack which attaches via your skewers is a "last resort".  The other half of the choice has to do with robustness and features.